# simulation of VANET security project

Tags: python, blockchain, simulation, simulator, sumo

I implement a VANET project with python and I use the blockchain in my project .
Now, I want to simulate my project . which is simulator that I can use it?

Comment: I don't know much about blockchains but for VANETs have a look at https://veins.car2x.org/ or https://www.eclipse.org/mosaic/. Unfortunatley they both do not use Python.

Answer (score 0):

The basis for selecting a particular tool for simulation depends on which performance parameters you are interested in to improve or study.

Basically we can classify the performance parameters as related to networking, computing ( memory is included here).

The simulation tools for each of these categories are different.

For networking related projects we use networking simulators like ns3, OMNET++,.etc.

1. https://github.com/ChuksXD/VANET-Blockchain

This is vanet security project based on python and hyperledger.

2. https://github.com/mmodenesi/omnetpy/

This is OMNET++ supplemented with python ( for non C++ programmers). Here you need to develop your own blockchain network core using python.